# How do I compute means in data frame in rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I am once again asking for you support!

I have the data frame, where different indecies on nation are presented, you can see them in the picture [image: here it is].

I want to compute all these indecies into one new variable but I do not know how to do it. I tried `rowMeans()` function but I might be a very stupid person, so I have not succeded in computing.

`mean()` did not worked - it appeared that "the argument is not numeric or logic: NAs to return".  I have also concerns that `mean()` computes the means in the whole column as a vector, not by the rows, as I need. **Once again** - I need to recieve means from nation# variables for each observation in the data frame.

Could anyone, please, help me with this pretty simple task?

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: @akrun I want a new varible with a value of ONLY "nation#" means

Comment: @r2evans sorry, my bad

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, plus verbatim errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: I've mentioned that I am the stupid person, haven't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowMeans` with `startsWith`

```
rowMeans(dat[startsWith(colnames(dat), "nation")])
```

Comment: Thank you, but this variant still computes means for all variables :(

Comment: @k1rgas it computes only for 'nation' variables (similar to the other answer)

Comment: I tried your variant and have recieved the whole NA column

Comment: @k1rgas do you have. NAs in the dataset or are the columns numeric?.  If it is not numeric, then it can end up with NA

Comment: there are no NAs, but other variables are factors or characters. not all the values are numerics or integers.

Comment: @k1rgas if the nation. variables are all numeric, then this should work because I tested on the data. provided in my competitors post

Comment: they are all numerics, and this still does not work :(

Comment: @k1rgas i meant have you checked `str(yourdata)`. and are all of them `numeric` class or `factor`

Answer (score 0):

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  nation1 = c(0,3,5,3,5,4), nation2 = c(4,2,5,3,5,4),
  ethnicity1 = c(5,5,5,5,5,2), ethnicity2 = c(5,5,5,2,4,4)
)
rowMeans(dat[, grepl("^nation", colnames(dat))])
# [1] 2.0 2.5 5.0 3.0 5.0 4.0
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did not help me though :(

Comment: Good luck, k1rgas. We don't have your data (you are *expecting* us to transcribe it manually), and you have not given us any errors. Then in your comment to akrun you said *"computes only for 'nation' variables"*, can you explain why that is at odds with your other comment *"want a new varible with a value of ONLY "nation#" means"*.